# Call a function according to a selected Key in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to do a weird thing here in Java.

I have a bean that has the following three functions:

```
bean.getOne()
bean.getTwo()
bean.getThree()
```

And I have a `key` that is a string which could have the following three possible values: `"one"`, `"two"` and `"three"`

What I want to do is call `bean.getOne()` if and only if key has value of `"one"` and so on.

How do I do the check and call the appropriate function?

Comment: how you get the key?

Comment: `switch ... case... ` ?

Comment: i made it complex. Key comes from a function call on a JSP page. a loop that prints the string array containing `one`, `two` & `three`. I have to check whether `one` or `two` or `three` could be empty and then if anyone of them is not empty, i have to call the function named similar to the `key`.

Comment: Why don't you try if/else. if(object == 1){ do something...}

Comment: Was this -1 necessary? Perhaps i am in the worst of my programming moods and you need to be easy on a guy who has just 68 points.! Seriously, people are ready to hit you hard here even if you make the slightest of mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all. I am the worst programmer ever. Give me a medal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to Java7

> In the JDK 7 release, you can use a String object in the expression of a switch statement:

You can use a [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) instead `if-else` statements for `String`s:

```
switch (key) {
   case "one":
      bean.getOne();
      break;

   case "two":
      bean.getTwo();
      break;

   case "three":
      bean.getThree();
      break;
}
```

Comment: Copy and paste is dangerous ;)

Comment: Thank u... i have lost my mind completely here. Forgot to use the hell basics. I am the worst programmer ever. Please give me the worst programmer ever badge!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get `String[] values` which can contain either `one, two or three`, you can try something like this:

```
if(values != null){
    List valuesList = Arrays.asList(values);
    if(valuesList.contains("one"){
        bean.getOne();
    }
    else if(valuesList.contains("two"){
        bean.getTwo();
    }
    else if(valuesList.contains("three"){
        bean.getThree();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` statements are so 90's.

With Java8 functional approach, you could create a lookup table of names and method references, like this:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
private Map<String, Function<Bean, String>> methods;
methods = new HashMap<>();
methods.put("one", Bean::getOne);
methods.put("two", Bean::getTwo);
methods.put("three", Bean::getThree);
```

And then use like this:

```
public String process(Bean bean, String selector) {
    return methods.get(selector).apply(bean);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.! Perhaps that is how i should have done it. Will do it this way as sson as i get time. :)

Comment: I am new to java so could you tell me what the `::` really does? Means it calls the function from the bean?

Comment: @IbrahimNadir It's a method reference. A way to "lift" a method to a function. See: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2191424&seqNum=2   and if you want to learn even more on functional programming go Scala.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think a `Switch` block or `if-else` would help:

```
switch (key.toString()) {
        case "one":
            bean.getOne();
            break;
        case "two":
            bean.getOne();
            break;
        case "three":
            bean.getOne();
            break;
        }
```